# Can a density function over $[0,+\infty)$ be zero at some point $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Tags: probability

That is:

Let $f(x)$ a probability density function defined over $[0,\infty)$.

**I wonder if it's possible that** $f(c)=0$ **for some** $c\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible that f(c)= O  for some .....

Comment: Makes no sense as stated. What goes after the =-sign? Also require context on this--especially if this relates to Bayesian statistics, where 'improper' densities are sometimes used for prior distributions.

Comment: Sorry, I wanna write $ f(c)= 0$

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible for all of the probability density to be located at $c = 0$?  If so, you may want to look up the Dirac delta function.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can take any density function and change it to be zero at any one point (or more generally, a set of zero measure) and still have a valid density function.

Example: $f(x) = e^{-x} \mathbb{1}_{x \geq 0, x \neq 1}$ is a valid density function for an Exp(1) random variable.

Comment: More simply, one can take $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{x \in [0,1]}$ which is just a uniform density on the unit interval. It is zero for all $c>0$.

Comment: I suppose you wanna say that it is zero for all $c>1$....

Answer (score 0):

For example a beta distribution.  Density
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^a(1-x)^b}{B(a,b)},\qquad 0 < x < 1
$$
and $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge 1$ and for $x \le 0$.